# Conditional statement for raster calculation R

Tags: r

In the context of a RUSLE erosion modelling I would like to calculate the sum of precipitation at the entry date of phenological phases.

Suppose I have 13 grids, one of which is the phenophase entry date `PhenoDate` with values from 1 to 356, the other 12 represent average daily shares of the annual precipitation sum for the individual months `[dPrecJan,...,dPrecDec]`.

I would like to calculate the precipitation sum using a set of conditional statements:

> If the phenophase begins in january, multiply the phenophase entry date with the january average daily precipitation,
>   else if the phenophase begins in february, multiply [...]"

I already tried to implement my conditional statements using the sum of products, where the condition returns either 0 or 1:

```
PrecSum <- ((PhenoDate<32) * PhenoDate * dPrecJan) + (
(PhenoDate>=32 & PhenoDate<60) * ((31*dPrecJan)+((PhenoDate-31) * dPrecFeb))) + (
(PhenoDate>=60 & PhenoDate<91) * ((31*dPrecJan)+(28*dPrecFeb)+((PhenoDate-59) * dPrecMar))) + (
( [etc.]))
```

Actually not too complicated construction, but since I use very high-resolution raster layers, the calculation goes beyond my memory capacities.

I'd appreciate any suggestions for a memory-efficient construction, which allows to set multiple conditional statements on my raster calculation.

Thank you in advance, 
Nils

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nils! I edited your question to make it better readable.

Comment: Which error do you exactly get?

Comment: There is no error message. The function works well with small raster layers. However, if I apply the function to my very large raster data (each grid > 5GB), my available disk space will be used up before the calculation is completed.